# TemplateDoesNotExist Django Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Решил развернуть Django-сайт на heroku.
После страданий с настройками сайт все же заработал, но не весь.

При попытке авторизоваться/залогиниться/открыть страницу пользователя (все эти страницы находятся в одном Django-приложении)
 выдает следующее:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом нормально работают все остальные приложения

**setting.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'forms'),],#Для загрузки из корня проекта
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns=[
url(r'^signup/$', views.signUp, name="signUp"),
url(r'^login/$',authen.login, {'template_name': 'userAuth/login.html'}, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', authen.logout, {'next_page': 'login'}, name='logout'), #Для перехода на главную страницу 'template_name': 'main/main.html'
url(r'^profile/(?P<u_id>[?a-z=A-Z0-9_.-]*)$', views.user_profile, name='edit_profile'),
url(r'^user/(?P<pk>\d+)$',DetailView.as_view(model = User, template_name = "UserAuth/viewe_user.html")),
]
```

Структура папок:

```
├───forms
│       basic.html
├───templates
│   │   logIn.html
│   │   profile.html
│   │   signUp.html
│   │   user_profile.html
│   │   viewe_user.html
│   │
│   └───userAuth
│           logIn.html
│           profile.html
│           signUp.html
│           user_profile.html
│           viewe_user.html
├───userAuth
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   forms.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───userAuth
│   │           logIn.html
│   │           profile.html
│   │           signUp.html
│   │           user_profile.html
│   │           viewe_user.html
```

Знает ли кто как решить проблему?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А на хероку нет подобных вопросов. Вроде, пол года назад, с потобным вопросом отправили именно туда, но это не точно. Че то связано с их особенностями

Comment: @ZaArs Возможно я туповат, но на хероку я не нашел ничего похожего на мой вопрос

Comment: чекните https://qa-help.ru/questions/heroku-ne-mozhet-najti-shablony-django

Comment: возмонжо надо написать так `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'forms'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),]`

Comment: @ZaArs Попробовал, не работает. Попробовал изменить temlate_name на:url(r'^user/(?P<pk>\d+)$',DetailView.as_view(model = User, template_name = "viewe_user.html")),url(r'^login/$',authen.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),  а html файлы из приложения перенес в папку forms в корне проекта и чудо, страница user стала работать! Однако login и logout все еще мертвы

Comment: у вас неправильно настроено django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в структуре папок logIn.html, а в маршруте login.html
И еще вот тут смотрите, где он шаблоны ищет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В самом деле, не знаю как не заметил. Но все равно не работает

Comment: смотрите картинку, там написано, где он шаблоны ищет

Comment: у меня он их ищет в django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/templates/userAuth/login.html (Source does not exist) и django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/userAuth/templates/userAuth/login.html (Source does not exist)  И по идее там эти файлы есть, однако он их не видит. Мне правда не понятно что такое папка app? В моем приложении ее нет. Это может быть корневая папка сайта куда heroku загружает мой django проект?

Comment: BASE_DIR - 'это он заканчивается на app. Попробуйте положить приложение в эту папку. Либо уберите app из BASE_DIR. Нужно, чтобы абсолютный путь был правильный

Comment: `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`  Разве не так должно быть?

Comment: да это не принципиально. Сделайте так: 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'forms'), 'templates'). И посмотрите, как изменятся пути поиска шаблона

Comment: смотрите python path и вот этот DIRS. Он склеивает эти пути и показывает вам ошибку, если там нет шаблонов

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У вас не работает, потому что вы указали искать шаблоны в папке `forms`. По этой же причине когде перенесли в forms, шаблоны заработали. Обновите настройки как в  коде ниже и должно заработать

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), 
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Также приложите структуру папок и файлов

Comment: Попробовал, без изменений. Самое интересное что на странице ошибки django говорит что искал файл в папке django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/templates/userAuth/login.html (Source does not exist) и ничего не нашел, что странно, ведь там этот файл есть. Правда я не понимаю что такое папка app, это корневая папка django-сайта? Добавил структуру папок и файлов.

Comment: При os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'forms'), все остальные приложения находят свои шаблоны, а приложение userAuth - нет

Comment: Интересно еще и то, что когда я запускаю сервер на localhost он видит все шаблоны нормально, а когда запустил на heroku появилась эта фигня

Comment: попробуйте указать полный путь к папке на heroku